# Why does my Java stream code output values like "streamsapi.product@5b480cf9"?

Tags: java, java-stream

I am checking this code to filter among collections data using stream API.
I am supposed to get list of two products which satisfy my condition
But I am getting output in decrypted format.

```java
package streamsapi;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StreamFilter {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*
         * List<product>list = new ArrayList<product>(); for (product product :
         * getProducts()) { if(product.getPrice()>2500f) { list.add(product); }
         * 
         * } for (product product : list) { System.out.println(product); }
         */
        
        
          List<product>list2 = getProducts().stream() .filter((product)->
          product.getPrice() > 2500f) .collect(Collectors.toList());
          list2.forEach(System.out::println);
         
    }
    private static List<product> getProducts(){
    List<product>ProductsList = new ArrayList<product>();
    ProductsList.add(new product(1,"hp",2500f));
    ProductsList.add(new product(2,"Dell",3500f));
    ProductsList.add(new product(3,"Asus",4500f));
    return ProductsList;
    
    }}
    class product{
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private float price;
        public product(int id, String name, float price) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;
            this.price = price;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public float getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
        public void setPrice(float price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
        
    }
```

And my output is:

```
streamsapi.product@3feba861
streamsapi.product@5b480cf9
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to override the `toString` in the `Product` class so that the `System.out::println` can print the object content not the reference

```java
class product{
    ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Product{" +
          "id=" + id +
          ", name=" + name +
          ", price='" + price + '\'' +
          '}';
    }
}
```